# Good React-Redux pattern to avoid infinite loops

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently, I'm creating an (extra?) action with the solely purpose of setting the *getSampleDataSuccess* var to false, so here's what I do:

1. On *componentDidMount*, I request some data from the API.
2. on *componentWillReceiveProps* I check for the *getSampleDataSuccess*.
3. If true (means success), then I request some more data.
4. If false, display error message.

The problem is that  *getSampleDataSuccess* is ALWAYS going to be true, unless it errors, but the point is that as far as  *getSampleDataSuccess* is true, I'll  be calling the second API request, thus infinitely looping. To avoid that I'm creating an extra action, to set  *getSampleDataSuccess* to false, once I've received the data, in componentWillReceiveProps.

Hope anyone can tell me what's the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having another state variable `getSampleDataInProgress`?

When `getSampleDataSuccess === true && getSampleDataInProgress === false`, request some more data, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: hmm .. makes sense, I'll try this method